# Multiple select queries in WHERE IN statement

Tags: mysql, sql, where-in

I have the following sql query :

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `prd_brand` AS `main_table`
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT value from catalog_product_entity_int where row_id in 
        (select row_id from catalog_product_entity_int where attribute_id = 97 and value = 1) , 
        (select row_id from catalog_product_entity_int where attribute_id = 99 and value = 4)) t 
ON main_table.brand_id = t.value
```

Is that possible to add multiple `select` queries in the `WHERE IN` statement.

BTW, when executing the query I have `#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what your query is trying to do.  But this seems like a simpler way to write the logic:

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM `prd_brand` AS b INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT value 
     FROM catalog_product_entity_int 
     WHERE (attribute_id, value) IN ( (97, 1), (99, 4) )
    ) t
    ON b.brand_id = t.value
```

Comment: This query gets all lines that have 97-1 AND 99-4 as attribute_id-value or 97-1 OR 99-4 ? I executed it and it seems like OR (and I need an AND between them).

Comment: @androniennn . . . You should ask another question being explicit about what you want.  Sample data and desired results help.